# Flask restx returning Class not the actual return string

Tags: flask

Recently I have been trying to add an api using flask-restx. I am having some toruble even getting a helloworld working.

I have everything in blueprints so it only make sense to place the api in its own blueprint also. Below is my api_routes.py

```
from flask_login import current_user, login_user, logout_user, login_required
from flask_restx import Resource, Api
from flask import Blueprint
import flask
from . import db

api_bp = Blueprint('api_bp', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(api_bp, version='1.0', title='Scribe API',
    description='An API for interfacing with Scribe',
)

@api_bp.route("/hello")
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello"

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello')
```

However if you go to the swagger ui and send a get like so:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/hello" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

The response is 500:

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a HelloWorld.
```

So for some odd reason I am returning the class and not the actual return string of "Hello". Does anyone have an idea of why this is and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move on shortly after posting this, it turns out namespaces are mandatory, you can fix my above code with the code below to create a namespace. This will get the basic helloworld working.

```
hello_ns = api.namespace('', description='Hello World Operations')

@hello_ns.route("/hello")
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello"
```